# magento create a csv file with product sku and categories for use witth magmi

Tags: php, magento, csv, magmi

I need to generate a csv file with product sku and the category tree, so I can later import it with Magmi On the fly category creator/importer plugin.

I need to get something like this:

```
sku;categories
"100";"My Products/Sample Products/Sample Category"
"101";"My Products/Other Products"
```

how can I achive this with php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.atensoftware.com/p187.php

Free Product Data Exporter for Magento

Comment: thankyou man, it exports a lot more, the categories came as json but broked my special chars, but I can manage to fix it through search and replace